# How to force to use Gutenberg in Worpress after install/uninstall clasic editor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I can not use Gutenberg in any way.. even with DEMO

[image]

**Description**

I want to use Gutenber in my site, but all post and pages always edit with the editor clasic. I've uninstalled clasic editor, and also all related plugins I had been using in the past. However, nothing happens. I can not use gutenberg. I installed Gutenberg Version 12.7.2 but I can not find where I need to configure or what I need to do more... It is really frustrating. Is there some configuration in the wordpress files where I can find another solution to force Gutenberg use technically? maybe some .php configuration file?

**Step-by-step reproduction instructions**

1. Go to Pages
2. Click on Edit any Page
3. Always open with Classic Editor.
4. I can not find any option related with edit with Gutenberg.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Environment info**
Wordpress version 5.9.1, Gutenberg 12.7.2, Theme GeneratePress 3.1.0
Problem in Chrome, Firefox, Edge.
Desktop windows 10, and Phone with Andriod 11

**Please confirm that you have searched existing issues in the repo.**
Yes

**Please confirm that you have tested with all plugins deactivated except Gutenberg.**
Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_true', 999);
```

Comment: Where can I add this line? In wich file?

Comment: current theme,  functions.php

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I also added another solution inspired on your answer.

Comment: I've been searching ages for this - and it worked like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also find a way to force wordpress to use Gutenberg in `post.php` file. It does not depend on the theme. (Make sure to create a copy of the original file).

[image]

Find function `use_block_editor_for_post` and add:

```
return true;
```

[image]